# Why is my google advanced search presenting this error?

Tags: html, cs50, advanced-search

i'm currently developing the project 0 (search) for the cs50x Web Programming with Python and Javascript and in the Advanced Search, when i submit the input given, que google query goes like this: tri-colour rat terrier miniature OR OR OR standard "rat terrier" --rodent (the OR appear 3 times and the "-" twice). I currently have no idea what may be causing it,  did someone algo have this problem?

Here's the html code i'm using:

Search
    
    
    
        
        
            Google Search

```
    <h1> Advanced Search</h1>
    <div id ="line"></div>

    <form action="https://www.google.com/search">
        <div class="grid">

            <p id="findPages">Find pages with...</p>
            <p></p>
            <p id="searchTip">To do this in the search box.</p>

            <label for="as_q">all these words:</label>
            <input class="advancedSearchInput" type="text" name="as_q" id="as_q">
            <p class="searchLabel">Type the important words: <span class="exemple">tri-colour rat terrier</span></p>

            <label for="as_epq">this exact word of phrase:</label>
            <input class="advancedSearchInput" type="text" name="as_epq" id="as_epq">
            <p class="searchLabel">Put exact words in quotes: <span class="exemple">"rat terrier"</span></p>

            <label for="as_oq">any of these words:</label>
            <input  class="advancedSearchInput" type="text" name="as_oq" id="as_oq">
            <p class="searchLabel">Type <span class="exemple">OR</span> between all the words you want: <span class="exemple">miniature OR standard</span></p>

            <label for="as_eq">none of these words:</label>
            <input class="advancedSearchInput" type="text" name="as_eq" id="as_eq">
            <p class="searchLabel">Put a minus sign just before words that you don't want: <span class="exemple">-rodent, -"Jack Russell"</span></p>

            <button class="advancedSearchButton" type="submit" value="Advanced Search">Advanced Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>    
    
</body>
```

Comment: The point of those fields is that you don't need to write the modifiers manually, the field adds them automatically. So for example in the "or" field you type just "miniature standard" and Google adds the "OR" in between automatically. If you type "miniature OR standard" then it adds two more ORs (one between "miniature OR" and one between "OR standard".)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going over and over the code to find a mistake and couldn't find it haha